# Compaq CQ58 with RT3290 and with OpenBsd 6.6 do not want to switch on WiFi card

Tags: wifi, network-interface, openbsd

I have Compaq CQ58 with combo wireless card RT3290. 
OpenBSD 6.6.

Wifi key F12 lights orange.

This command:
    ifconfig ral0 scan
says, besides other info, that `status: no network` 
and that `cannot scan, interface is down`

Before installing OpenBSD, I had Win8 and the Wifi ran normally.

Now, I am trying to press wifi key (F12) for short, fort long, with Fn, without Fn. I tried to reset bios to default. I tried take out battery. Nothing helps.

Some hint, what to try?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the chipset's firmware?  If the board was present during installation, it should have been installed automatically on the following boot, provided that the machine had internet access.  If internet access was unavailable at that time or if the board was attached later, you'll need to install the firmware manually by running `fw_update` as `root`.  You can check which firmwares are installed and which are missing (if any) by running `fw_update -i`.

`/var/log/messages` or `dmesg` might also provide some information about what is going on.  If the firmware is installed you can try bringing the interface up (`ifconfig ral0 up`) before scanning. Also note that there might be an hardware switch at play (either a literal physical switch or a BIOS setting), but this does not seem to be the case, since you've been looking at the BIOS settings already.